# What is this pipe and why is it leaking?

Tags: plumbing, leak, pipe

I noticed a leak inside our master bedroom closet. The kitchen sink is on the other side of this wall. I pulled up the floorboard and cut out some wet drywall to find an open pipe and found that  water trickles from this pipe when the sink is running.

(*This closet is connected to the master bath and bedroom. It's part of an extension that was built onto the house several years ago before we purchased it. The house was originally built in the 60's.*)

Does anyone know what this pipe is and why it would start leaking?

[image]

Comment: It is very difficult to see details in the photo and  it shows no context as to how or where it comes from or its orientation or what material it is.

Comment: Are there any "extra" pipes connected to your drain in the kitchen?

Comment: It's 2" D, made of steel, and runs horizontal or parallel to the ground.

Comment: Found one end.  Need to find the other end.  Also check below that level to see if any more damage was caused.

Comment: Jack - Other than the dishwasher drain line going into the drain for the sink, there are no extra pipes on the kitchen drain.

Comment: I can't imagine it's a vent stack that someone cut off.  I'd cap it with a rubber cap and hose clamp to prevent further damage while you continue to investigate. You could try running a plumbers snake through some of your pipes to see if the end comes out there or vice verses.

Comment: It is may some drain pipe. After renovation not properly sealed. All drains should be connected to vertical pipe,  going up to roof and release sewage gases. It may be some unused branch. Just seal that.

Comment: It seems time for a visit from the plumber.

Answer (score 0):

We can’t see what the pipe is very well but guessing because it is below a sink it may be a clean out point.

A location that a snake is normally run down the drain to clean it out and the plug failed.